# Remote debugging - Java

Tags: java, maven, batch-file, java-7, remote-debugging

I am currently with a batch process that breaks into production, which is in a weblogic. This process can only be executed on a machine that is configured to run automatically.
My question is if a remote debugging can be done from my machine?

Answer (score 1):

I really would not recommend remotely debugging a machine which is on production.  However, if you must, you will need to do three things:

1. Startup the application with remote debugging turned ON on a port 80 or any other port of your choice by adding the following line to your java -jar command.

> `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=80`

For example,

> `sudo java agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=80 -jar original-example-service-local.war`

2. This port needs to be accessible from your machine, you will need to open this port from your security group in AWS or however you are managing this instance. This step is very important.
3. Add the configuration in your IDE to do remotely connect to the application. You can find many guides on this online.

   > For IntelliJ --> https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/tasks/sdk-debug-intellij.html
   >   For Eclipse --> https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/tasks/sdk-debug-eclipse.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: but if the process is in another machine, is it enough to put the port in the configurations or do I have to clarify something else?